Blank display after upgrade
I have a Dell tower server with an NVIDA quadro NVS 420 graphics card in it. I recently upgraded from 22 to 24.04 and have lost the display. And I’m really stuck, because I can’t get a terminal. So I can’t edit files to force nouveau.
At boot, I get the Ubuntu splash screen on all four displays, but once the drivers load (I assume) all four screens go black. I can’t open a terminal. Or if one is opening, it’s not displayed. To add insult to injury, I get the same thing with a live CD… A black screen and no way to see a terminal.
Anyone have advice for resolving this?

I forgot to mention I don’t get the grub menu, either

To get the grub menu assert {ESC} during boot.

Boot to grub. 'e' on the broken boot menu selection. change the "quiet spash" to "text" then continue boot. Or select a previous kernel or Advanced Options->Recovery mode

This question is similar to: How to switch to a command-line console. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
